# Trying to Use the InfoRecoverySample in IS 5.0.0

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying t use the InfoRecoverySample in IS 5.0.0. I was able to build it as according to the instructions here:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recovering+Account+Information+Using+a+Webapp

However after placing the war file in [IS_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/webapps/ and restarting, I get errors in the application logs.  Unfortunately they are very vague:

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Error occurred while deploying webapp : [IS_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/webapps/InfoRecoverySample.war

Error occurred while deploying webapp : [IS_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/webapps/InfoRecoverySample.war

Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[InfoRecoverySample.war].File[repository/deployment/server/webapps/InfoRecoverySample.war]
```

My best guess is that the pom.xml file is out of date because I see lots of references to 4.2.0.  This is the pom.xml file I'm using:
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/chamathg/samples/is/InfoRecoverySample/pom.xml

Does it sound like I'm on the right track?  If so, is there an updated pom.xml file (or sample project) out there?

TIA,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the war file in your tomcat/webapps folder, not the identity server webapps. then access via localhost:8080

edit:
The way the pom is designed is for deployment on your localhost, not the wso2 server. Despite what the instructions say. However, you can deploy it to [IS_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/webapps/ as long as you remove most of the jar files that are created in the war's WEB-INF/lib directory. These will conflict when being run from the IS. The only one you need to leave is org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent-1.2.0.jar. remove, re-zip, and then redeploy.